# Matplotlib "heavy" 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I need to plot a 3D scatter plot using python. The visualisation required having a points cloud showing some points belonging to a region and some others to another region.

Here is an example. My real task requires doing this with shapes that are not described by an equation but the task is similar

import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
points = np.linspace(-10,10,50)
xx,yy,zz = np.meshgrid(points,points,points,indexing='ij')

# cylinder in the meshgrid
cylinder_coordinates = zz**2+yy**2 <= 4

xxCyl = xx[cylinder_coordinates]
yyCyl = yy[cylinder_coordinates]
zzCyl = zz[cylinder_coordinates]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(xx,yy,zz,alpha=0.2)
ax.scatter(xxCyl,yyCyl,zzCyl,c='red')
```

Already with the above code, my computer struggles rendering the output. With the   real task, it takes forever. Does someone have an idea how to perform this task but make it "lighter" ?

The data I am looking to visualise has nothing to do with statistical variables. It is a pure geometrical problem. I need to demonstrate that the points belonging to the geometry are correctly classified according to the different regions and that therefore I perform the correct operations with them.

Comment: You might want to look at the datashader library

Comment: Have you calculated what you are plotting? The size of xx alone is 50^3 = 125000 and the total size is 3*(50^3 + 3800) = 386400. With this in mind, it might be a good idea to sample from x, y, and z before creating the meshgrid.

Comment: Hence the word heavy in the title. The number of points is 50^3, not times 3 if I am correct.

Comment: Take the time to read comments carefully.

Comment: I read it carefully. "The size of xx alone is 50^3" how do you compute that ?